# How should I access the <tr>in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having following code snippet:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr id="24655">
    <td>
        <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=72224,24655,69412#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE24655</a>
        <a class="c-icn c-remove delete_question" onClick="return ConfirmDelete()" title="Delete question"> Delete</a><br />        
    </td>
    <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">         
        92.86<br />                       
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now can you tell me how should I access the `<tr id="24655">` in jQuery after clicking on the hyperlink given in `<a>` tag in above code?

Comment: you mean on the delete link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inlined event handler in favor of jQuery one

```
<table border="0">
    <tr id="24655">
        <td> 
            <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=72224,24655,69412#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE24655</a>  
            <a class="c-icn c-remove delete_question" title="Delete question"> Delete</a>
            <br />
        </td>
        <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">92.86
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then inside the event handler `this` refers to the clicked element, so you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `tr` element and then use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the id attribute

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.delete_question').click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.closest('tr').attr('id');
        alert(id);

        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/amrL6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
try closest
   var i = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
   console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `this` in **onclick function** call and than collect the **object and convert it to jquery object** but I suggest you follow **Arun P Johny's** answer because in that case you don't have to change any code in markup.

```
<table border="0">
  <tr id="24655">
    <td>
        <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=72224,24655,69412#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE24655</a>
        <a class="c-icn c-remove delete_question" onClick="return ConfirmDelete(this)" title="Delete question"> Delete</a><br />        
    </td>
    <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">         
        92.86<br />                       
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function ConfirmDelete(obj) {
    console.debug($( this ).parent('tr[id]'));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0">
  <tr id="24655">
    <td>
        <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=72224,24655,69412#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE24655</a>
        <a class="c-icn c-remove delete_question" onClick="return ConfirmDelete()" title="Delete question"> Delete</a><br />        
    </td>
    <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">         
        92.86<br />                       
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a.c-remove').click(function(){
          var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            alert(tr.attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>
```